# Finite sum of reciprocal factorials

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, graph-theory

Does someone know how to calculate sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(n-k)!\cdot k} $? I was working something with matrices, i.e. calculating number of all cycles in Coates digraph, and got this weird expression(multiplied by $n!$) Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hm. With the multiplication by $n!$, each summand has the form

$$\binom n k \cdot (k-1)!$$

I wonder if that means anything.

Comment: Are you certain that it's $k$ in the denominator and not $k!$? (That's a factorial and a question mark, not an interrobang.)

Comment: Maybe try sticking an $x^k$ to it each term. Then it becomes some polynomial. If you differentiate this polynomial it takes on the form. $$ \frac{1}{(n-1)!} + \frac{1}{(n-2)!}x + ...$$ but it’s not clear if this direction is fruitful.

Comment: It looks like a convolution of $\frac{1}{k}$ with $\frac{1}{k!}$ - so its generating function would probably be something like $e^x \cdot (-\ln(1-x))$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a closed form for your sequence, other than the hypergeometric

$$ {\frac {{\mbox{$_3$F$_1$}(1,1,1-n;\,2;\,-1)}}{ \left( n-1 \right) !}}$$

but the generating function is

$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^n}{(n-k)! k} = -e^x \ln(1-x)$$